# MySQL - Grouping By results from Selects in Selects

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently performing a query which contains two selects in the select. I want to do a group on the results returned in order to do a count (to in turn create a pie chart)

The system I'm trying to query contains a table of images. Each image may have zero or more bits of metadata. The available metadata can vary from image to image hence it's served by a separate table rather than columns as part of the images table.

So the table structure is:

```
Image {
   image_id (PK)
}

ImageMetaDataKey {
   metadata_key_id (PK),
   key
}

ImageMetaDataValue {
   metadata_value_id (PK),
   value
}

ImageMetaData {
   image_id (FK - Image.image_id),
   metadata_key_id (FK - ImageMetaDataKey.metadata_key_id ),
   metadata_value_id (FK - ImageMetaDataValue.metadata_value_id )
}
```

My current SQL statement is:

```
SELECT i_o.image_id, (SELECT imdv.value
    FROM Image i, ImageMetaDataValue imdv, ImageMetaDataKey imdk, ImageMetaData imd
    WHERE imdk.metadata_key_id = imd.metadata_key_id 
    AND imd.metadata_value_id =imdv.metadata_value_id  
    AND (imdk.key='Camera Model')
    AND i.image_id=imd.image_id
) as Camera, (SELECT imdv.value
    FROM Image i, ImageMetaDataValue imdv, ImageMetaDataKey imdk, ImageMetaData imd
    WHERE imdk.metadata_key_id = imd.metadata_key_id 
    AND imd.metadata_value_id =imdv.metadata_value_id  
    AND (imdk.key='Lens Model')
    AND i.image_id=imd.image_id
) as Lens
FROM Image i_o
GROUP BY i_o.image_id;
```

which returns:

```
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
| image_id | Camera                | Lens                                |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
|       11 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM            |
|       15 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM            |
|       24 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM            |
|       28 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF16-35mm f/2.8L USM                |
|       29 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF16-35mm f/2.8L USM                |
|       34 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS            |
|       35 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS            |
|       37 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM            |
|       43 | Canon EOS 7D          | EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM            |
|       48 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM            |
|       49 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF70-200mm f/2.8L USM               |
|       50 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF70-200mm f/2.8L USM               |
+----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Ideally I want to run something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(i_o.image_id) as 'Count   ', (SELECT imdv.value
    FROM Image i, ImageMetaDataValue imdv, ImageMetaDataKey imdk, ImageMetaData imd
    WHERE imdk.metadata_key_id = imd.metadata_key_id 
    AND imd.metadata_value_id =imdv.metadata_value_id  
    AND (imdk.key='Camera Model')
    AND i.image_id=imd.image_id
) as Camera, (SELECT imdv.value
    FROM Image i, ImageMetaDataValue imdv, ImageMetaDataKey imdk, ImageMetaData imd
    WHERE imdk.metadata_key_id = imd.metadata_key_id 
    AND imd.metadata_value_id =imdv.metadata_value_id  
    AND (imdk.key='Lens Model')
    AND i.image_id=imd.image_id
) as Lens
FROM Image i_o
GROUP BY i_o.image_id, Camera, Lens;
```

which would return:

```
    +----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
    | Count    | Camera                | Lens                                |
    +----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
    |        5 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM            |
    |        2 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF16-35mm f/2.8L USM                |
    |        2 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS            |
    |        1 | Canon EOS 7D          | EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM            |
    |        2 | Canon EOS 450D        | EF70-200mm f/2.8L USM               |
    +----------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use two levels of aggregation.  First to get the two models:

```
SELECT imd.image_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN imdk.key = 'Camera Model' THEN imdv.value END) as camera_model,
       MAX(CASE WHEN imdk.key = 'LENS Model' THEN imdv.value END) as lens_model
FROM ImageMetaData imd JOIN
     ImageMetaDataKey imdk
     ON imdk.metadata_key_id = imd.metadata_key_id JOIN
     ImageMetaDataValue imdv
     ON imd.metadata_value_id = imdv.metadata_value_id  
GROUP BY imd.image_id;
```

Then use this as a subquery to get your counts:

```
SELECT camera_model, lens_model, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT imd.image_id,
             MAX(CASE WHEN imdk.key = 'Camera Model' THEN imdv.value END) as camera_model,
             MAX(CASE WHEN imdk.key = 'LENS Model' THEN imdv.value END) as lens_model
      FROM ImageMetaData imd JOIN
           ImageMetaDataKey imdk
           ON imdk.metadata_key_id = imd.metadata_key_id JOIN
           ImageMetaDataValue imdv
           ON imd.metadata_value_id = imdv.metadata_value_id  
      GROUP BY imd.image_id
     ) cl
GROUP BY camera_model, lens_model;
```

Note very importantly the use of proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Nice use of `MAX` and `GROUP BY` to avoid the double join.

Answer (score 1):

Because I found the question interesting I created an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76263bf/12) by reverse-engineering the result of your first query. I then rewrote the query like so:

```
SELECT i.image_id,
       imdata1.value AS Camera,
       imdata2.value AS Lens
FROM Image i
JOIN (SELECT imd1.image_id, imdv1.value FROM ImageMetaData imd1
      JOIN ImageMetaDataKey imdk1 
        ON imdk1.metadata_key_id = imd1.metadata_key_id AND
           imdk1.key = 'Camera Model'
      JOIN ImageMetaDataValue imdv1
        ON imdv1.metadata_value_id = imd1.metadata_value_id
      ) AS imdata1 ON imdata1.image_id = i.image_id
JOIN (SELECT imd2.image_id, imdv2.value FROM ImageMetaData imd2
      JOIN ImageMetaDataKey imdk2
        ON imdk2.metadata_key_id = imd2.metadata_key_id AND
           imdk2.key = 'Lens Model'
      JOIN ImageMetaDataValue imdv2
        ON imdv2.metadata_value_id = imd2.metadata_value_id
      ) AS imdata2 ON imdata2.image_id = i.image_id
```

Output:

```
image_id    Camera              Lens
11          Canon EOS 450D      EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM
15          Canon EOS 450D      EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM
24          Canon EOS 450D      EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM
28          Canon EOS 450D      EF16-35mm f/2.8L USM
29          Canon EOS 450D      EF16-35mm f/2.8L USM
34          Canon EOS 450D      EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS
35          Canon EOS 450D      EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS
37          Canon EOS 450D      EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM
43          Canon EOS 7D        EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM
48          Canon EOS 450D      EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM
49          Canon EOS 450D      EF70-200mm f/2.8L USM
50          Canon EOS 450D      EF70-200mm f/2.8L USM
```

The reason I rewrote it was to put it in a form that was more suitable for grouping:

```
SELECT COUNT(i.image_id) AS `Count`,
       imdata1.value AS Camera,
       imdata2.value AS Lens
FROM Image i
JOIN (SELECT imd1.image_id, imdv1.value FROM ImageMetaData imd1
      JOIN ImageMetaDataKey imdk1 
        ON imdk1.metadata_key_id = imd1.metadata_key_id AND
           imdk1.key = 'Camera Model'
      JOIN ImageMetaDataValue imdv1
        ON imdv1.metadata_value_id = imd1.metadata_value_id
      ) AS imdata1 ON imdata1.image_id = i.image_id
JOIN (SELECT imd2.image_id, imdv2.value FROM ImageMetaData imd2
      JOIN ImageMetaDataKey imdk2
        ON imdk2.metadata_key_id = imd2.metadata_key_id AND
           imdk2.key = 'Lens Model'
      JOIN ImageMetaDataValue imdv2
        ON imdv2.metadata_value_id = imd2.metadata_value_id
      ) AS imdata2 ON imdata2.image_id = i.image_id
GROUP BY Camera, Lens
```

Output:

```
Count   Camera              Lens
5       Canon EOS 450D      EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM
2       Canon EOS 450D      EF-S18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS
2       Canon EOS 450D      EF16-35mm f/2.8L USM
2       Canon EOS 450D      EF70-200mm f/2.8L USM
1       Canon EOS 7D        EF-S17-55mm f/2.8 IS USM
```